# How to loop through entire data beyond the scope of pagination

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to build a web application using `laravel/vue` combined. I have used pagination to display the list of users from users table.My table has a column for user_type.
Since I'm using pagination,I'm not being able to count each user type in my front end(Just counts from only the data returned by `controller->paginate(5)` ). I tried to use some helper functions in controller but that didn't work out well.

So I'm asking is there a way to loop through and count all data in users table from vue file while still using pagination in controller?

## userController

```
public function index()
{
    $this->authorize('isAdmin');
    return User::latest()->paginate(5);
}
```

## users.vue

```
methods: 
{
    getResults(page = 1) {
        this.$Progress.start();
        axios.get('api/user?page=' + page)
            .then(response => {
                this.users = response.data;
                for(let i=0; i<this.users.data.length; i++){
                    if (this.users.data[i].user_type == 'admin')
                        this.admins++;
                    if (this.users.data[i].user_type == 'surveyor')
                        this.surveyors++;
                    if (this.users.data[i].user_type == 'user')
                        this.standard_users++;
                }
                        // console.log(this.admins);
                        //  console.log(this.surveyors);
                        //   console.log(this.standard_users);
        });

        axios.get('api/form-one')
            .then(response => {
                this.lists = response.data;
                this.forms = this.lists.data.length;
                // console.log(this.lists.data.length);
        });

        this.$Progress.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can return a $total_count variable from the controller.

Comment: I tried to return some variable with count of each user types....but if I do so my pagination breaks down as it should

Comment: by the way it worked, thank you for the idea :D

Comment: You are welcome. Please share how you solved the problem. It might help future learners.

Comment: yes of course. I have provided the solution in my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by returning four variables instead of one.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->authorize('isAdmin');
    $admin = User::where('user_type','admin')->selectRaw('count(user_type) as admin')->get()->toArray();
    $surveyor = User::where('user_type','surveyor')->selectRaw('count(user_type) as surveyor')->get()->toArray();
    $normaluser = User::where('user_type','user')->selectRaw('count(user_type) as normaluser')->get()->toArray();
    $user = User::latest()->paginate(5);
    return response()->json([$admin,$surveyor,$normaluser,$user]);
}
```

And got the response in vue by direct accessing of arrays

```
methods: {
            getResults(page = 1) {
                 this.$Progress.start();
                        axios.get('api/user?page=' + page)
                            .then(response => {
                                this.users = response.data;
                                this.admins = this.users[0][0].admin;
                                this.surveyors = this.users[1][0].surveyor;
                                this.standard_users = this.users[2][0].normaluser;

                            });
                            axios.get('api/form-one')
                                .then(response => {
                                    this.lists = response.data;
                                    this.forms = this.lists[0][0].form;
                                    console.log(this.forms);
                                });
                    this.$Progress.finish();
            },
    },
```

May not be best way to do that but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination does in fact return a total count.

It is accessible via: `rsp.data.total` where as your data is stored in `rsp.data.data`.

Below is a sample response from the `paginate(50)` function.

```
current_page: 1
data: [mydatahere]
first_page_url: "https://someurl.com/items?page=1"
from: 1
last_page: 2
last_page_url: "https://someurl.com/items?page=2"
next_page_url: "https://someurl.com/items?page=2"
path: "https://someurl.com/items"
per_page: 50
prev_page_url: null
to: 50
total: 92
```

Comment: Sir,I needed to check the user_type also. How can I extract that information?

Comment: I don't know what your data structure is, so without more information. I cannot help you further. I would assume it's under `response.data.data.users[0].user_type` at a random guess.

Comment: Yes, I had to randomly guess its returning indices. Just got the job done for this case but it should not be the proper way for this problem